# AWS Target Tracking deployment a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am working on a Rails application that I want to scale horizontally using AWS Target Tracking and AWS Auto Scaling Group. I also, want to have the deployment as Blue Green where I don't have any downtime in the application.

I just wanted to know the steps and best practices that I can follow to do deploy updates on a regular basis. Thanks

Comment: I never used it, but did some research on it for my last project, and you might want to check out [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/). Is supports blue-green deployments into auto-scaling groups, and should be pretty easy to set up. Might be what you need...

Comment: @jdno Thanks for responding. I will check AWS Code Deploy. In addition to managing the rolling deployments to the current instance. I just wanted to the best practices around how the same set of updates could potentially be passed on to AWS Scaling group and such. Thanks